# Solving probability from joint PDF

Tags: probability

What am I doing wrong?

My thinking for solving this probability: 
First I attain the marginal probability density of $f(x,y)  \rightarrow \ f_x(x) $
Then attain the integral. However I am receiving a value greater than 1.

$$
  f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
4x^3,  & \text{0 < y < x < 100} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

$$ P(x>2) = \int_{2}^{100} f_x dx $$

where $f_x$ is the marginal probability density for the joint probability density

Comment: I think something's wrong with the joint pdf, as it doesn't seem to have total integral $1$.

Comment: @carmichael561 Is my methodology correct though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your plan.   That is just what you need to do.

$$\mathbb P(X>2) =\int_2^{100}\color{blue}{\underbrace{\bbox[lemonchiffon,0.5ex]{\color{black}{\int_0^x f(x,y)\operatorname d y}}}_{f_X(x)}}\operatorname d x$$

The only issue is that you do not have a valid probability density function.

$$\int_0^{100}\int_0^x 4x^3\operatorname d y\operatorname d x \neq 1$$